# What does Islam say about lying to stay in the UK for a British passport?

Tags: halal-haram, family, non-muslim-countries, lying, taqiya

I have a question regarding someone lying to stay in the UK for a British passport

I know someone who came as a visitor to the UK and rather than going back abroad decided to claim asylum on domestic violence. Saying her husband has beaten her and has chucked her out with her two daughters, which is a lie she has told to claim asylum.  Her husband had agreed to it when she put the claim in.

5 years ago her husband's visa expired and he had to go back to the country he came from, and the British Embassy there have his passport so he can't apply for a visa in Britain, because of what she has stated on her asylum claim.

Her 2 daughters don't remember their dad but miss him when other kids mention their dads, the girls are aged 9 and 7, she has applied for indefinite leave to remain in the UK on the grounds of domestic violence.

What does Islam say about this? Because from my understanding it's a lie: she is living for a UK passport and the girls are missing out to be with their dad.

Answer (score 4):

With some exceptions which don't apply here, lying is forbidden in Islam:

> ... it is not lawful to lie except in three cases: Something the man tells his wife to please her, to lie during war, and to lie in order to bring peace between the people.
>   <sub>[Jami` at-Tirmidhi 1939](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/27/45) [grade: sahih]</sub>

The negative consequences (in this case, children missing out on contact with their father) are what happens when people lie.  It also spreads mistrust of Muslims, and makes it more difficult for people who have genuine asylum claims.

It's likely these actions would be considered [visa fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_fraud), which I presume is illegal in the UK.  Muslims are required to obey the law of the land ([Dar Al-Ifta](http://daruliftaa.com/node/5852)).

Finally, the Qur'an describes an appropriate course of action:

> Indeed, those whom the angels take [in death] while wronging themselves - [the angels] will say, "In what [condition] were you?" They will say, "We were oppressed in the land." The angels will say, "**Was not the earth of Allah spacious [enough] for you to emigrate therein?**" For those, their refuge is Hell - and evil it is as a destination.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 4:97](https://quran.com/4/97)</sub>

In fact, the Qur'an continues:

> ... whoever emigrates for the cause of Allah will find on the earth many [alternative] locations and abundance ...
>   <sub>[Qur'an 4:100](https://quran.com/4/100)</sub>